# ORA-01400 : Strange behavior

Tags: oracle, insert, null

Oracle Database 11g Enterprise Edition Release 11.2.0.3.0 - 64bit Production

A, B, C and D are VARCHAR2

E is a DATE

(A,B,C,D, E) is the primary key of TABLEDESTINATION

```
truncate table TABLEDESTINATION;

INSERT  /*+ parallel(10) */  INTO TABLEDESTINATION (A,B,C,D, E)
  SELECT
    TABLE1.DATA1,
    TABLE2.DATA2,
    TABLE2.DATA3,
    NVL(TABLE3.DATA4, '-') DATA4,
    TRUNC(TABLE1.DATA_DATE ,'MONTH') DATA_DATE
  FROM TABLE1 
    INNER JOIN TABLE2 ON TABLE1.DATA1 = TABLE2.DATA1 AND TABLE1.Z = TABLE2.Z
    LEFT JOIN TABLE3 ON TABLE1.X=TABLE3.X
  GROUP BY 
    TABLE1.DATA1,  TABLE2.DATA2, TABLE2.DATA3, 
    NVL(TABLE3.DATA4, '-'),  TRUNC(TABLE1.DATA_DATE ,'MONTH');
```

**Will result in "ORA-01400: cannot insert NULL in ("USER"."TABLEDESTINATION"."E")"**

Now if I use the exact same query, but using a temporary table :

```
truncate table TABLEDESTINATION;

CREATE TABLE TEST_TABLE AS
  SELECT
    TABLE1.DATA1,
    TABLE2.DATA2,
    TABLE2.DATA3,
    NVL(TABLE3.DATA4, '-') DATA4,
    TRUNC(TABLE1.DATA_DATE ,'MONTH') DATA_DATE
  FROM TABLE1 
    INNER JOIN TABLE2 ON TABLE1.DATA1 = TABLE2.DATA1 AND TABLE1.Z = TABLE2.Z
    LEFT JOIN TABLE3 ON TABLE1.X=TABLE3.X
  GROUP BY 
    TABLE1.DATA1, TABLE2.DATA2, TABLE2.DATA3, 
    NVL(TABLE3.DATA4, '-'),  
    TRUNC(TABLE1.DATA_DATE ,'MONTH');

INSERT  /*+ parallel(10) */  INTO TABLEDESTINATION (A,B,C,D, E)
  select DATA1,DATA2,DATA3, DATA4, DATA_DATE
  from TEST_TABLE;
```

**Lines are correctly inserted, without any errors.**

Now I try the same query, but with a NVL for the date :

```
INSERT  /*+ parallel(10) */  INTO TABLEDESTINATION (A,B,C,D, E)
  SELECT
    TABLE1.DATA1,
    TABLE2.DATA2,
    TABLE2.DATA3,
    NVL(TABLE3.DATA4, '-') DATA4,
    /* -> */ NVL(TRUNC(TABLE1.DATA_DATE ,'MONTH'), SYSDATE) /* <- */ DATA_DATE
  FROM TABLE1 
    INNER JOIN TABLE2 ON TABLE1.DATA1 = TABLE2.DATA1 AND TABLE1.Z = TABLE2.Z
    LEFT JOIN TABLE3 ON TABLE1.X=TABLE3.X
  GROUP BY 
    TABLE1.DATA1,  TABLE2.DATA2, TABLE2.DATA3, 
    NVL(TABLE3.DATA4, '-'),  
    /* -> */ NVL(TRUNC(TABLE1.DATA_DATE ,'MONTH'), SYSDATE) /* <- */
  ;
```

**Lines are correctly inserted, without any errors.**

Logically, it would mean that I have NULL values in the DATA_DATE :

```
SELECT
  TABLE1.DATA1,
  TABLE2.DATA2,
  TABLE2.DATA3,
  NVL(TABLE3.DATA4, '-') DATA4,
  NVL(TRUNC(TABLE1.DATA_DATE ,'MONTH'), SYSDATE) DATA_DATE
FROM TABLE1 
  INNER JOIN TABLE2 ON TABLE1.DATA1 = TABLE2.DATA1 AND TABLE1.Z = TABLE2.Z
  LEFT JOIN TABLE3 ON TABLE1.X=TABLE3.X
WHERE 
  TABLE1.DATA_DATE IS NULL
;
```

**Returns 0 line**

```
SELECT
  TABLE1.DATA1,
  TABLE2.DATA2,
  TABLE2.DATA3,
  NVL(TABLE3.DATA4, '-') DATA4,
  NVL(TRUNC(TABLE1.DATA_DATE ,'MONTH'), SYSDATE) DATA_DATE
FROM TABLE1 
  INNER JOIN TABLE2 ON TABLE1.DATA1 = TABLE2.DATA1 AND TABLE1.Z = TABLE2.Z
  LEFT JOIN TABLE3 ON TABLE1.X=TABLE3.X
WHERE 
  TRUNC(TABLE1.DATA_DATE) IS NULL
;
```

**Returns 0 line**

How is it possible that I have no NULL values in DATA_DATE yet Oracle throws me a ORA-01400 ?

How is it possible that using a temporary table, with the exact same query, I don't get the same error ?

EDIT :
Like suggested, I also tried using DISTINCT :

```
INSERT  /*+ parallel(10) */  INTO TABLEDESTINATION (A,B,C,D, E)
  SELECT DISTINCT
    TABLE1.DATA1,
    TABLE2.DATA2,
    TABLE2.DATA3,
    NVL(TABLE3.DATA4, '-') DATA4,
    TRUNC(TABLE1.DATA_DATE ,'MONTH') DATA_DATE
  FROM TABLE1 
    INNER JOIN TABLE2 ON TABLE1.DATA1 = TABLE2.DATA1 AND TABLE1.Z = TABLE2.Z
    LEFT JOIN TABLE3 ON TABLE1.X=TABLE3.X
```

Returns the following error : **ORA-12805: parallel query server died unexpectedly**

EDIT2 : If I remove the parallel hint, I get this error : "**ORA-00001: unique constraint (ZRA.ZRAQX_VENTE_DOPR_MOIS_PK2) violated**"
Which I still donc understand, since I am using a GROUP BY on the Primary Key, and I dont have any NULL values...

EDIT3 : I tried using an implicit cursor :

```
FOR CURTEST IN (/* same select as above */) LOOP
INSERT INTO TABLEDESTINATION (A,B,C,D,E) values (CURTEST.DATA1,CURTEST.DATA2,CURTEST.DATA3,CURTEST.DATA4, CURTEST.DATA_DATE);
END LOOP;
```

And surprise : It works ! No errors.

Nothing makes sense any more ...

Comment: But how come INSERT   INTO TABLEDESTINATION select * from TEST_TABLE  works (see end of query 2) ? and like i said, there are no NULl values in DATA_DATE like explained (see query 4 and 5). And no Triggers.

Comment: E never gets the actual SYSDATE, so the NVL is never used.

Comment: Like you said, it looks like a bug, but since 99% of time people say it's a bug, it's actually a human error ;)

Comment: The only constraint is the primary key. So it has an implicit not null constraint. But no default value. My DBAs are looking at the issue on their side also, but no luck so far.

Comment: I forgot to mention: I'm using parallel hint in the insert.  I can try without it, but it would take me about 11 hours of runtime....

Comment: If it's running for so long (presumably much less than 11 hours with parallel, but still hours?) are you sure your query to check for nulls is seeing the same data the actual query saw? (Maybe you can check with a flashback query?) Is this reproducible when there is no other activity, or was it a one-off failure?

Comment: It is a datawarehouse, data change only during night time batches. I was able to reproduce this behavior everytime I tried (I'm on this "bug" since last Friday). I only encountered this problem on PreProduction environnement. I need to test again in Dev server tomorrow when I can, but the problem is that Dev is running on 10g. (dont ask me why ;)). And I obviously won't try on Production yet. About the 11 hours runtime, it is based on Production time of the old batch without parallel, which I am trying optimize.

Comment: Is it possible to try 3rd example with `sysdate` replaced by some constant value(e.g. `to_date('00010101','yyyymmdd')`) and examine `TABLE1.DATA_DATE` values if such dates found in resulting dataset? E.g. `select * from (<your_third_select>) where data_date = to_date('00010101','yyyymmdd')` ?

Comment: Just for sure: **1.** Is all queries run in same environment (DB instance, client application, session settings)? **2.** Is all tables in examples (`TABLE1`, `TABLE2`, `TABLE3`) are tables (not views, procedures etc.)?

Comment: Is your first query fails if you replace `GROUP BY` with `DISTINCT`?    `INSERT INTO TABLEDESTINATION (A,B,C,D, E)
  SELECT` **`DISTINCT`** `TABLE1.DATA1,
    TABLE2.DATA2,
    TABLE2.DATA3,
    NVL(TABLE3.DATA4, '-') DATA4,
    TRUNC(TABLE1.DATA_DATE ,'MONTH') DATA_DATE
  FROM TABLE1 
    INNER JOIN TABLE2 ON TABLE1.DATA1 = TABLE2.DATA1 AND TABLE1.Z = TABLE2.Z
    LEFT JOIN TABLE3 ON TABLE1.X=TABLE3.X` **`;`** You don't need `group by` because there are no grouping functions in select list.

Comment: Tested on 10g, with sample data of 10M (originally about 120M) : no problems. Like suggested, I replaced GROUP BY by DISTINCT, and there I get ORA-12805: parallel query server died unexpectedly. Although in my examples I dont use grouping functions, I actually need them, but are irrelevent to the error I get. Since I already have work-arounds, I am only hoping to find the cause of these errors.

Comment: I edited the question with new errors I encountered. My DBAs also concluded on an Oracle parallel bug. But cannot explain the primary key exception yet ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the origin of the bug :

```
TRUNC(TABLE1.DATA_DATE ,'MONTH') DATA_DATE
```

If I use this instead :

```
TRUNC(TABLE1.DATA_DATE ,'MM') DATA_DATE
```

It Works !

I was able to reproduce the error with MONTH after.

So it really was an Oracle bug with the TRUNC and 'MONTH'

Thank you all for your advices.